# OSGEO4W Installer avce00.exe error

Tags: osgeo4w, windows-10

The latest OSGeo4W Installer reaches 100% and then throws an error:

> Unable to extract /bin/avcexport.exe -- the file is in use. Please
> stop all OSGeo4W processes and select "Retry", or select "Continue" to
> gon on anyway (you will need to reboot).

- stop OSGeo4W processes as it cannot extract avce00.exe (when you think about this one, it's quite funny as if you stop all those processes you are stopping the installer as well and there you are in an frustrating loop)

Things to know:

- when I click 'Continue' it just throws the error again
- it occurs whether I do an express or an Advanced Install
- I have yet to run an advanced and deselect avce00.exe - should I?
- when I search through the files, processes and systems running on the machine, I cannot find reference to it
- I have cleared out my temp folder prior to running the installation
- I have deleted my OSGEO folder on my c drive
- is it just an angry ESRI Gremlin and I am on its naughty list

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this when I installed this as an administrator.