# QGIS OSGEO4W Install Error - Unable to Extract /bin/BGSPAWN

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, osgeo4w

I am getting this error when I try to install QGIS-Dev

[image]

[image]

I have

- checked the Process Log and also run Process Explorer but can't find
  BGSpawn anywhere.
- searched all of C drive.
- checked
  https://www.mail-archive.com/osgeo4w-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg03256.html. Same issues as this post.

I have also tried the older QGIS Dev and am using the osgeo4w-setup I downloaded today and the [download.osgeo.org](https://download.osgeo.org) site. Just trying norbit.de as well on the QGIS-Full as well.

**Update**

When I try the QGIS-Full from Norbit.de I get
[image] -

I cannot find avcexport.exe in the process log, either.

Searching for this error, I found the following post and am just trying his solution - [OSGEO4W Installer avce00.exe error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409601/osgeo4w-installer-avce00-exe-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [OSGEO4W Installer avce00.exe error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409601/osgeo4w-installer-avce00-exe-error)

running the installer as admin worked -even though my account was admin anyway and other software doesn't require this.

Leaving the question here, instead of deleting it for anyone that searches for the BGSpawn error.